# Get name of selected item of list elements in same page by disappear of listed elements , using $stateProvider concept in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie to angularJS,can anyone provide me an example regarding my concept,i am unable to implement this routing of parent element with node of child elements with $stateProvider routing concept.

when i click on trees,it has to display fruits and flowers in nav bar with active mode of fruits,flowers list in another page,we can redirect to both pages.

when i click on mango it has to display its div along with its name,i did some work on it,can anyone help to reach my work completely?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/YvDMtE0IOZCIdVM9EReN?p=preview

Comment: I did up to here,how to reach complete task?

Comment: I don't know where you tried to copy that code from, but you have 2 different unfinished solutions in there. One is about trees/animals/fruits, the other is about report/news/notebook. How are you planning on merging them? So far your links `url` and partials `templateUrl` are wrong

Comment: instead of `href="#news"` it should be `ui-sref="reportsBuilder"` (for example), and reportsBuilder should point to `trees.html` (?) instead of `reports.html`; something is clearly mismatched

Comment: I have found several issues with your code.

Comment: pardon,my upload plunker is not working properly,(report/news/notebook) are belong to my project,so when i am replace  my details  with other words it  was appearing like that,i didn't copied from anywhere.Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues which you need to address.

**index.html**

> instead of ref, use ui-sref.

**app.js**

> Here state should be exactly what you are specifying with the ui-sref.
>
> I see templateUrl given by you are missing.

Check this simple [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router) to start with ui-routing

Comment: @JhansiRani. Thanks. Please upvote if you like the solution.